# Emptying a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to clear all elements from an array object (which can be a standard PHP array, an ArrayObject or basically any other object that implements the basic array interfaces such as Itertable, ArrayAccess, Countable etc.). However, I do not want to reinstate the object, so I somehow have to unset all the individual elements, instead of creating a new object of the same type. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you want to reinstate an object/array?

Comment: Because the object is a function parameter, and I do not necessarily have knowledge of where it comes from or how to instantiate it.

Answer (score 5):

```
foreach ($array as $key => $element) {
    unset($array[$key]);
}
```

This requires both `Traversable` and `ArrayAccess`, `Countable` is not required. Or obviously just a normal array.

Comment: Using that gives me the following error: ArrayIterator::next(): Array was modified outside object and internal position is no longer valid

Comment: @mrjames: Hm, seems like arrayiterator is pretty strict. On arrayobject I would simply call `exchangeArray`, but arrayiterator doesn't have something like this.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure why you need to do it this way, but in answer to your question, you should be able to simply use the [array_splice](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) function to remove all of the objects from your array;

```
$my_array = array('A', 'B', 'C');
array_splice($my_array, 0);
```

I've never used array_splice to remove all objects from an array, but I assume it works in the same manner.

Comment: @nikic Ahh, my bad. Upvote given to your answer as it better matches the question criteria!

Answer (score 1):

I am having trouble deciphering what the question is really asking for. Replacing the array/iterator with an empty iterator (an `EmptyIterator`, or another iterator with no values?) might suffice.

```
$array = new EmptyIterator;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try**

```
$my_array = array('A', 'B', 'C');
unset($my_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about a simple unset?

unset($array);

Answer (score 0):

In case you remove the last record from array than the next foreach loop can fail (internaly calling $this->next() )

So it helped me to test the validy and break in this case the next loop.

```
deleteOffset = true;

foreach ($iterator as $key => $value)
    {
            if ($deleteOffset && $iterator->offsetExists($key) ) 
            {
                 $iterator->offsetUnset($key);                                       
            }                

        //if remove last record than the foreach ( $this->next() ) fails so 
        //we have to break in this case the next ->next call         

        if (!$iterator->valid()) break;

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The best place PHP Manual

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php